# com.sun.jersey.api.client.UniformInterfaceException: returned response status 404 !

Tags: java, rest

Всем привет. 
После попытки решить свою проблему не смог найти ответов в интернете, и на этом сайте.. и решил дать пример своей проблемы.. непонятно почему получаю эту ошибку и что она значит.. насколько я знаю 404 это не правильный URL адрес при обращении, но не могу понять что тут не правильного.

main method:

```
public class ApplTest {

private static final String URL = "http://localhost:8080/MyTests";
private static final String INT_R = "/calculations/integerCalculation/";

 int integer = 12;
 double d = 4.5;

@Test
public void main(){

     ClientConfig config = new DefaultClientConfig();
     Client client = Client.create(config);
     WebResource resource = client.resource(URL);

     WebResource one = resource.path("rest").path(INT_R +integer);

     String res = new Service().IntegerValueService(one);

     System.out.println(res);

     String res2 = new Service().GerResponseAsXML(one);

     System.out.println(res2);
}

}
```

service class:

```
public class Service {

public String IntegerValueService(WebResource resource){

    return resource.accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML).get(ClientResponse.class).toString();
}

public String GerResponseAsXML(WebResource resource){


    return resource.accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML).get(String.class).toString();
}
```

resource class:

```
@Path("/calculations")
public class Calculator {

@GET
@Path("/integerCalculation/{integerValue}")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
public int integerCalculation(@PathParam("integerValue")int value){

    int result = 0;
     result = value/2;

     System.out.println(result);

    return result;
}
```

web.xml:

```xml
<display-name>MyTests</display-name>

<servlet>
  <servlet-name>ServletTest</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
    <param-value>service</param-value>
  </init-param>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>ServletTest</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

stack trace:

```
com.sun.jersey.api.client.UniformInterfaceException: GET http://localhost:8080/MyTests/rest/calculations/integerCalculation/12 returned a response status of 404
at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.handle(WebResource.java:563)
at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.access$300(WebResource.java:69)
at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource$Builder.get(WebResource.java:451)
at service.Service.GerResponseAsXML(Service.java:17)
at appl.test.ApplTest.main(ApplTest.java:35)
```

Comment: А что за метод `GerResponseAsXML(one)`?

Comment: Добавил метод, сори и спасибо за комент.

Comment: И в первом случае работает, а во втором падает, я правильно понимаю?

Comment: В первом случае возврашает 404, якобы ненаходит по тому пути ресурс (calculator).  Дожно вернуть 200 ок. 
Во втором да ты прав.

Comment: А если дернуть URL из браузера?

Comment: Тоже самое 404 ненаходит.. Пользуюсь Postman.

Comment: <h1>HTTP Status 404 - /MyTests/calculations/integerCalculation/12</h1> Из браузера.

Comment: Попробуйте убрать префикс `/rest` из URL-а и из web.xml

Comment: Вот туториал на основе которого я попробовал сделать.. 
http://www.java2blog.com/2013/04/create-restful-web-servicesjax-rs-using.html 
7 урок. Может чтото нетак там и у меня.. хотя вроде тот же принцип. 
Папробувал убрать непомогает.